# Rewriting function without for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I currently have this function to fetch youtube videos:

```
    function searchYouTube(searchstringYT, white2) 
{
var yt_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' + searchstringYT + '&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc'; 
    $.ajax({
        url : yt_url,
        dataType : "jsonp",
        success: function (json)
        {
            var result= json.data.items; 
                for (i in result)
                {
                    if (result[i].title.toLowerCase().indexOf("live") >= 0)
                    {
                        $(".whiteDiv2").html(""); 
                        $("<h2/>").text("LIVE")
                        .appendTo(white2);
                        $("<h3/>")
                        .text(result[i].title)
                        .appendTo(white2);
                        $("<iframe/>")
                        .attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+result[i].id)
                        .css({
                                "width":"620",
                                "height":"400"
                            })
                        .appendTo(white2);
                    }

                }
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is: I do this with a for loop, but I only need to do it for one video..
My question is: how do I remove the for loop, since I only need to run this loop once?

Also for some weird reason: if I add a else{} to my if(result..) function, the else is always executed, it just skips the above part. With the else left out, it always does the if part though...

Comment: result[0], I guess? If you just want the first item.

Comment: @Jori: Assuming `result` is an array. Using `for-in` suggests otherwise.

Comment: I only want the first item, where do I add the result[0] exactly?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah I see: `for-in` loops through the enumerable properties of an object, not the indexes of an array. I'm coming from C, so just guessed the syntax :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to stop after one iteration, add:

```
break;
```

...just before the `}` closing the loop body.

Note that the order in which the property names are visited in a `for-in` loop is *not defined*, and so you'll be picking one "at random." (In fact, it won't be random on any particular implementation, and *most* implementations visit the keys in the order the properties were added to the object, but it's not specified behavior.)

Of course, if `result` is an array, you shouldn't be using `for-in` on it in the first place (at least, [not without safeguards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)). If that's the case, you can remove the loop and use `result[0]` where you're currently using `result[i]`. (Assuming the array isn't sparse.) For instance:

```
if (result[0].title.toLowerCase().indexOf("live") >= 0)
// Here ---^
```

...and also in the other places you use `result[i]`.

Comment: First of all: thanks for your reply!
Unfortunately I did exactly as you said (remove the for loop, and replace result[i] by result[0] everywhere, but now the code won't work. Any idea why this may happen?

Comment: As T.J. pointed out in another post, [I suggest you read this good explanation about `for-in`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html). EDIT. Oh lol, it is ftrom T.J. haha.

Comment: @user3162496: See the *first* part of my answer. Sounds like `result` isn't an array.